# Android: Show BottomSheetDialog from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I have a BroadReceiver and want to show a BottomSheetDialog after receiving a notification of my app, even if my app is not running. When I use the context from onReceive().
I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mypackage.myapp.NotificationReceiver: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

I suppose I need the context of an activity, but how to get it here?

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. The reason is as stated in the error that you got i.e. *is your activity running*. Any sort of dialog needs a valid context to run. If the context is invalid, the dialog will not be shown

Comment: To elaborate a bit further, yes it can be done if the activity that received the broadcast is running. *even if my app is not running* is what is not possible